# How to call textview from Linear Layout via include layout in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to change the TextView in android using java for that I have to call the ID of that TextView in my java class. but I am getting error like "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android. widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference". Below is the full scenario...

Here is my one layout of that TextView:

xyz layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/Heading.LinearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/nature_lovers"
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            style="@style/Heading.LeftHeading"/>

    </RelativeLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

I am calling the above layout to another layout using "include" like this:

```
<include
 layout="@layout/xyz"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In Java I am trying to set the text to that TextView like this:

```
headingText = mView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
holder.headingText.setText("Hello Developers");
```

Butting getting error like:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

Please tell me the solution of how can I set TextView in android using Java.

Comment: Why are you calling holder.headingText? I think it should be just headingText.

Comment: please post your activity/fragment code so we can give you a specific solution. we are not clear about your code.

Comment: what is mView? if this `headingText = mView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
holder.headingText.setText("Hello Developers");` is in your activity and the activity textview is in your main activity then remove mView. Otherwise, post your Activity/fragment /class code

Comment: Assign layout id to your include layout. View search should be something like this -> mView.findViewById(R.id.includeLayout).findViewById(R.id.heading);